# ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to integrate the Google firestore API in my python program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/firestore.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.cloud import firestore # pylint: disable=import-error,no-name-in-module
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import __version__
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from google.cloud.firestore_v1._helpers import GeoPoint
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.api_core import gapic_v1
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/config.py", line 23, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc import _compression
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 15, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Code/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import firestore
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/firestore.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImportError('Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure '
ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python. Make sure to install the "google-cloud-firestore" module.
```

I have this error and have tried every option I have found

I installed the firebase-admin module:

```
pip3 insstall --upgrade -t libs firebase-admin
```

I installed grpc:

```
pip3 install grpcio
```

I installed google-cloud-core and google-cloud-firestore:

```
pip3 install google-cloud-core
pip3 install google-cloud-firestore
```

I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling all of these modules. But nothing seems to be working. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to reinstall pip. `python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it advised to install packages using `python -m` command instead of simply `pip` or `pip3`.

Try installing as follows:

```
python3.7 -m pip install google-cloud-firestore
```

Additionally, I would recommend using a virtual environment.

```
# Create a virtual environment using Python3.7
$ python3.7 -m venv env
# Activate the virtual environment
$ source env/bin/activate
# Install dependencies 
(env) $ python3.7 -m pip install google-cloud-firestore
```